# Rampant low Vitamin D

Tags: human-biology, vitamins

Why have people inadequate vitamin D status? Is it just (the lack of) sun exposure, or is it related to hormone and thyroid function?

Comment: @MarchHo - how about this edit?

Comment: As far as I know by  inadequate vitamin D the thyroid must produce more thyroid hormone to compensate. I don't think the vitamin D status depends on the thyroid function. I'll look for references.

Answer (score 4):

Here in Australia there are more cases of vitamin D shortage than in England. Given the [double amount of sun hours per annum](http://www.bobinoz.com/blog/17598/the-sun-in-australia/) here in Down Under, that's quite counter intuitive. In fact, an estimated 31% of adults in Australia have inadequate vitamin D status, increasing to more than 50% in women during winter–spring and in people residing in southern states [(Nowsen *et al*., 2012)](https://www.mja.com.au/journal/2012/196/11/vitamin-d-and-health-adults-australia-and-new-zealand-position-statement).

It turns out that in Australia people are, rightfully, careful of sun exposure due to the thin ozone layer and the resulting high incidence of skin cancer. As a result, people here wear long-sleeves on the beach, use high-factor sunscreens, wear sun hats, use umbrellas to evade the sun *etcetera*. The [Australian  Cancer Council](http://www.cancer.org.au/preventing-cancer/sun-protection/campaigns-and-events/slip-slop-slap-seek-slide.html) supports the famous "slip, slop, slap" slogan:

> Slip on a shirt, slop on sunscreen and slap on a hat, Slip, Slop, Slap! You can stop skin cancer [..]!

Hence, folks here in fact often take vitamin D supplements, despite the large amounts of sun hours.

<sub>**Reference**

**-** [Nowsen *et al*., *MJA* (2012); **196**(11): 686-7](https://www.mja.com.au/journal/2012/196/11/vitamin-d-and-health-adults-australia-and-new-zealand-position-statement)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Vitamin D deficiency is most probably the cause of the thyroid disfunction and not the result. So the cause of vitamin D deficiency is the lack of UV exposure.

> To  conclude,  the  results  of  the  present  study  suggest  that
>   moderate  to  severe  vitamin  D  deficiency  is  a  risk  factor  for
>   hypothyroidism. As vitamin D deficiency is highly prevalent in north 
>   Indian  population,  these  findings  may  ha ve  some  public health 
>   implications. Further, large  scale  clinical  trials  and prospective
>   studies  will  be  required  to  establish  a  cause  and effect 
>   relation  of  vitamin  D  deficiency  in  pathogenesis  of
>   hypothyroidism.     Supplementation     of     vitamin     D     in
>   hypothyroi dism  may  ameliorate  its  symptoms  and  prevent further
>   deterioration of thyroid function, so, for the ease, safety and   low 
>   cost   of   treating   this   modifiable   risk   factor   we
>   recommend its screening in all hypothyroid patients.

- 2014 - [VITAMIN D LEVELS CORRELATED WITH HYPOTHYROIDISM IN INDIAN POPULATION: A PILOT STUDY](http://recentscientific.com/sites/default/files/download_69.pdf)

> In the present study, we demonstrated that serum vitamin D levels were
>   significantly lower in female GD patients without remission than in
>   those with remission.

- 2013 - [Serum vitamin D levels are decreased in patients without remission of Graves’ disease](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12020-012-9789-6/fulltext.html)